# comparing a list of filename with file containing a list of filename in azure storage account in python

Tags: python, pandas, azure

here the code df extracts the contents of the file line by line
and the next part for loop goes inside the list of files containing configuration file

here the list of files in blob is compared with file(configuration file) conataining a list of files

```
import azure
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
# importing datetime module 
import datetime 
#from azure.storage.blob import BlobServicefrom azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import azure
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
# importing datetime module 
import datetime 

#### this df is used to read all the contents of a file (configuration file)
######sas url of sample file
import pandas as pd 
source ='https://punithrameshstorage.blob.core.windows.net/inputblob/CONFIGURATION_FILE.txt?sp=r&st=2020-08-26T08:18:36Z&se=2030-08-27T16:18:36Z&spr=https&sv=2019-12-12&sr=b&sig=MVFoPPxeDY8iYXjF0sEIcberile7YF3fiZAlUhhE%2FKs%3D'
df = pd.read_csv(source)
print(df)


### here its is used to enter the conatiner inside we try to compare the filenames with configuration file containing files
#connect_str = os.getenv('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=punithrameshstorage;AccountKey=lYF6CBSJOGe4C/Zg5NCCzn7xkztccYB8G05kYSQ+a+kE4WdDk2E2f4qjaInqXBLM1ytZ12u3P2y/PRdSofNBGw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=punithrameshstorage;AccountKey=lYF6CBSJOGe4C/Zg5NCCzn7xkztccYB8G05kYSQ+a+kE4WdDk2E2f4qjaInqXBLM1ytZ12u3P2y/PRdSofNBGw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("inputblob")
def right(value, count):
# To get right part of string, use negative first index in slice.
    return value[-count:]

def right1(value, count):
# To get right part of string, use negative first index in slice.
    return value[-count:]
timer=0
# List the blobs in the container
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    name=str(blob.name).replace('.txt','')
    right(name,8)
    name[:-8]
    print( name[:-8])
    if(name !='CONFIGURATION_FILE'):
       # print(name[:-8])
        #print(df)
        timer+=1
        print(timer)
        if(name[:-8] == any(df) ):
            print (df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere in the above code?

Comment: yes, i cannot copy list of files from one container to another container(this container having folders) and